# Java version issue "Could not determine java version from '12.0.1'"

Tags: java, jdk, minecraft

I am trying to code a minecraft mod, but that is not the problem.
I have to extract a folder using the `gradlew` command:

```
gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
```

The problem: Every time I try to perform this command, an error gets thrown.

I tried to install an older JDK (8) but I have to create an account. However, it seems to be required to work on some sort of a company (They ask all this stuff, like work-phone-number).

Is there any way I can get my hands on the JDK 8 version?
(Is there an Oracle students account?) 
Or how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is no longer maintaining OpenJDK 8. If you are using OpenJDK from the default Ubuntu repositories, Oracle's license cancellation doesn't matter at all because Ubuntu will continue to support their Java packages the same way they support every other package in their repositories.

If you dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 or install Ubuntu 18.04 in a virtual machine, you can install OpenJDK 8 from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

You can also install NetBeans or Eclipse IDE for Java Developers from the Ubuntu Software app in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to build and get APK for an old Unity 3D project (so that I can play the game in my Android phone). I was using the most recent Android Studio version, and all the SDK packages I could download via SDK Manager in Android Studio. SDK Packages was located in

C:/Users/Onat/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk 
And the error message I got was the same except the JDK (Java Development Kit) version "jdk-12.0.2" . JDK was located in

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2
And Environment Variable in Windows was JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2

After 3 hours of research, I found out that Unity does not support JDK 10. As told in https://forum.unity.com/threads/gradle-build-failed-error-could-not-determine-java-version-from-10-0-1.532169/ . My suggestion is:

1.Uninstall unwanted JDK if you have one installed already. https://www.java.com/tr/download/help/uninstall_java.xml

2.Head to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

3.Login to/Open a Oracle account if not already logged in.

4.Download the older but functional JDK 8 for your computer set-up(32 bit/64 bit, Windows/Linux etc.)

5.Install the JDK. Remember the installation path. (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/)

6.If you are using Windows, Open Environment Variables and change Java Path via Right click My Computer/This PC>Properties>Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables>New>Variable Name: JAVA_HOME>Variable Value: [YOUR JDK Path, Mine was "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221"]

7.In Unity 3D, press Edit > Preferences > External Tools and fill in the JDK path (Mine was "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221").

8.Also, in the same pop-up, edit SDK Path. (Get it from Android Studio > SDK Manager > Android SDK > Android SDK Location.)

9. If needed, restart your computer for changes to take effect.